# Find Max Id from list which has children of same list

Tags: c#, lambda

I have a list of Persons which has children [same type]. I get the list from xml file.

**Scenario :**

Person : Id, Name, Gender, Age, Children [Class with fields]

If personList has 1,2,5 Ids,
2 and 5 with children 3,4 and 6,7,8 respectively.
I have to get the max id as 8.

How do i get the max of Id from PersonList using lambda expression?

Comment: How many levels of children could there be?

Comment: There could be probably 2 levels. But in certain cases i can have more levels also (upto 10). My scenerio is little different from the above mentioned scenerio.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try a combination of [`Concat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx) and [`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx) (that's assuming it's only nested one level):

```
var maxId = personList.Concat(personList.SelectMany(p => p.Children)).Max(p => p.Id);
```

**UPDATE**
If you have multiple nesting levels, you could also write an extension method to make `SelectMany` recursive:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> SelectManyRecursive<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> selector) {
    if (source == null) { yield break; }
    foreach (var item in source) {
        yield return item;
        foreach (var selected in selector(item).SelectManyRecursive(selector)) {
            yield return selected;
        }
    }
}
```

That doesn't handle circular references and it behaves differently than `SelectMany` by also returning the items in the source collection itself (so you might want to change the name), but otherwise i think it does the job. You could use it quite easily:

```
var maxId = personList.SelectManyRecursive(p => p.Children).Max(p => p.Id);
```

Comment: Given he now wants up to 3 levels, would you add another level of `Concat`/`SelectMany` or recommend something recursive?

Comment: @Rawling I updated my answer to include a short example of a recursive approach.

Comment: Great... I was going to +1 you for that but it appears I already _did_ :-/

Comment: I will not have any circular references in my list. Whats the diff between your extension method and SelectMany().                     Can I get the same from below statement without above extension method?:                                                          var maxId = personList.SelectMany(p => p.Children).Max(p => p.Id);

Comment: @VVutpala No, `SelectMany` only selects `Person.Children` for the top-level items. It will not select any deeper nested items. It also won't select the items in the original collection (1,2,5). `SelectMany` would give you only 3,4,6,7,8 and it would ignore their children (if any). `SelectMany` is designed to be able to select a return type different than the source type, and that wouldn't allow for recursion (because the type of the selector function wouldn't match).

Answer (score 0):

I switched your scenario sligthly by adding another level.
If this does not help please post an example of your data objects.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace App
{
    public enum ID{
        one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eigth, nine, ten
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public ID id;
        public List<Person> children;
        public Person(ID id, List<Person> children)
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.children = children;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        private static List<Person> BuildScenario()
        {
            return new List<Person>{
                new Person(ID.one, new List<Person>()),
                new Person(ID.two, new List<Person>{
                    new Person(ID.three, new List<Person>{
                        new Person(ID.ten, new List<Person>())
                    }),
                    new Person(ID.four, new List<Person>())
                }),
                new Person(ID.five, new List<Person>{
                    new Person(ID.six, new List<Person>()),
                    new Person(ID.seven, new List<Person>()),
                    new Person(ID.eigth, new List<Person>())
                })
            };
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Person> scenario = BuildScenario();
            Console.WriteLine(CountIDs(scenario).ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(GetMaxID(scenario).ToString());
            while(true);
        }

        private static int CountIDs(List<Person> scenario)
        {
            int count = 0;
            foreach (Person person in scenario)
            {
                count += 1 + CountIDs(person.children);
            }
            return count;
        }


        private static ID GetMaxID(List<Person> scenario)
        {
            ID maxid = 0;
            foreach(Person person in scenario)
            {
                ID childmax = GetMaxID(person.children);
                if (person.id > maxid) maxid = person.id;
                if (childmax > maxid) maxid = childmax;

            }
            return maxid;
        }
    }
}
```